# Rotate a Block of Text

Tags: code-golf

### Rules

- Write a program in a language of your choice.
- That program is designed to rotate a block of text. Example:

  ```
  BOB   90 deg  DCB
  CAT    -->    OAO
  DOG    CW     GTB
  ```
- You may assume the blocks of text are loaded into a variable `block`.
- You may assume a square block, but of any size.
- You may assume the line-endings are `\n`.
- You're not allowed to use a library that already rotates blocks of text.
- Code Golf rules, shortest program wins.

Comment: Rotate in which direction? 90 degrees clockwise, or is that just an example?

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, 11 characters

```
n/-1%zip n*
```

Explanation:

```
n/  # split on newline
-1% # reverse array
zip # "rotate" (will turn ['abc' 'def' 'ghi'] into ['adg' 'beh' 'cfi'])
n*  # join with newline again
```

Comment: Didn't he say that you cannot use an predefined method which rotates the text ? Seems like `zip` is doing that only

Comment: This can be improved by one char. See [my answer to the question it duplicates](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20170/194)

Answer (score -4):

## Python, 0 bytes

My program rotates the block of text by 720 degrees.

Comment: Problem, it does not echo.